# Getting average, min, and max with mid

Tags: excel, excel-2007

This is my sample value

```
P70330624047
P67430533047
P67260716036
P71380627037
```

I'm trying to get the average, min, and max of `mid(value,2,2)` which is 70, 67, 67, and 71.

For max, i used this formula

```
=MAX(MID(A3:A6,2,2))
```

but it's returning 67 as the max. What's wrong here?

I also tried putting the `mid(value,2,2)` value in another cells(using the formula) so that I have cells which is only

```
70
67
67
71
```

but when i get max here, i get `0`.

It's the same for average and min, i'm getting wrong results.

Comment: mid can not used on a range. so you have to put mid in another cells

Comment: No, that isn't correct - you can use a single array formula, I.e. =MAX(VALUE(A3:A6,2,2)) - confirmed with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER

Comment: Sorry, I missed MID function out, should be: MAX(VALUE(MID(A3:A6,2,2)))

Answer (score 0):

because mid return string. you need to use NUMBERVALUE(MID(v,2,2)).

```
P70330624047    70
P67430533047    67
P67260716036    67
P71380627037    71
Max             71
```

Comment: I don't think NUMBERVALUE is available in Excel 2007 - try just VALUE

Comment: @barryhoudini, sorry not his fault. When he wrote his answer I realized I didn't specify excel version so I just edited it in

Comment: No problem, does it work with VALUE? You can use a single formula......but it needs to be "array entered" - see my comment above